# Make Image fit within the parent View

Tags: react-native

I have an `Image` inside a `View` to which I have set maximum height and width. How to make the image element fit inside the parent element? If the image's height is longer than the width, then let the image reach the maximum of the parent element's height. If the image's width is longer than the height, then let the image reach the maximum of the parent element's width.

My code:

```
...
<View style={styles["view"]}>
  <Image
    source={{ uri: ... }}
    style={styles["image"]}
  />
</View>

...

"view": {
  position: "relative",
  justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center",
  maxHeight: 400, maxWidth: "90%"
},
"image": {
  position: "relative",
  resizeMode: "contain",
  flex: 1
},
...
```

The `Image` element currently is not appearing with the above style.

Comment: move `maxHeight` and `maxWidth` style props to `styles.image` instead of the `view`

Comment: @HagaiHarari, I tried those settings but the `Image` is not appearing at all.